# 00:02 deploy:check:linked_files ERROR linked file /home/deploy/mynewapp/shared/config/master.key does not exist on x.x.x.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running into issues when trying to run the cap production deploy command.

I first got this error message:

```
00:02 deploy:check:linked_files
ERROR linked file /home/deploy/mynewapp/shared/config/database.yml does not exist on X.X.X.X
```

Then I copied the database.yml file from my dev server to my prod server on X.X.X.X

I re-ran cap production deploy command, and got this error message:

```
00:02 deploy:check:linked_files       
ERROR linked file /home/deploy/mynewapp/shared/config/master.key does not exist on x.x.x.x
```

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 3.2.1 (2023-02-08 revision 31819e82c8) [x86_64-linux]

$ rails -v
Rails 7.0.4.2
```

Thoughts as to what I can try next? I do not see a master.key on my dev server to copy to prod server.

Answer (score 1):

This was the answer to my question. I ran this command `EDITOR=nano rails credentials:edit` on my dev server to create the master.key file.